# C# Which Event should I use to display data in a textbox when I select an item in a listbox?

Tags: c#, listbox

C# Which Event should I use to display data in a textbox when I select an item in a listbox?

I want to select an item in a list box (winforms) and then a textbox near by show some data related to that item but I don't know which event to use. I'll need to be able to click down the list and watch the textbox text update with each click.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You will want to handle either [`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) or [`SelectedValueChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged.aspx).

(Note that the `SelectedValueChanged` MSDN article has an example that sounds like exactly what you are doing.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a form with a TextBox and a ListBox.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bindingcontext.aspx) will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't know the exact name of the event off the top of my head, but is something like **SelectedItemChanged** that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Is the [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event not working for you?

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    relatedTextbox.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```